# Unit testing SAF file/directory operations

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I am trying to implement unit tests for Android code that utilizes `DocumentFile` instances for file/directory operations. Normally it would be possible to initiate these tests by picking a location using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, but I am unable to get an instance of `DocumentFile` as part of such unit test (without needing user interaction).

It would be perfectly sufficient for my use case if I were able to convert a location in application's private storage to `DocumentFile`, but converting a `file://` URI of a directory to `DocumentFile` does not seem possible.

Comment: "but converting a file:// URI to DocumentFile does not seem possible." -- [`DocumentFile.fromFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#fromFile(java.io.File)) works, last I checked.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough - in my case I want to convert a directory to `DocumentFile` (as the code works with a directory and generates a set of files and subfolders there). I used `fromTreeUri` in this case, is there another way?

Comment: AFAIK, `fromFile()` will work for both files and directories, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it does work, I don't see how I missed it. Can you write it as an answer? I would be happy to accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `DocumentFile.fromFile()` is less than clear, but it works for files and directories. As opposed to `Uri` values — where you need to call `fromSingleUri()` or `fromTreeUri()` to distinguish documents from trees — `fromFile()` can figure that out on its own.